# The basic structure of the Scala code in Flink CEP application

Tags: scala, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I have tried to understand how to CEP in Flink works. For example from pages:
[DataArtisans LongRides](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_scala/cep/LongRides.scal) and [Flink CEP 1.4](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/libs/cep.html).

I would like to know what is the basic structure of the (Scala) code in Flink CEP application ?

What (mandatory) parts, classes, functions/methods and so on should be used and in what order ?

I think the basic parts could be:
1. pattern definition
2. pattern stream definition (or is it possible to use many parallel streams ?)
3. select definition
Is that correct ?

And how to use the "select part" and how to find more information about it ? It seem to be quite complex.

Comment: What would be the very simple full working CEP apllication ?

Answer (score 0):

The structure that you've written is basically correct. You need to define pattern and stream of events that you want to apply that pattern to. Then you should apply `select` function which allows you to apply some logic to events that constitute a match.

The best source to get more info how the FlinkCEP works is its [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/libs/cep.html).